# How to use setMuted() in qml file Qt Android

Tags: android, qt, controls, volume, qmediaplayer

This is probably a very noob question... I am very new to Qt, and trying programming in Qt creator. Now I created a new Qt Quick Application from Qt creator, and I play a audio and i would like control volume and mute but idon't know how.

```
        Button {
            id: muteButton
            onClicked: mediaPlayer.muted ...
            text: qsTr("Mute")

        }

        Slider {
            id: volumeSlider

            Layout.fillWidth: true
            maximumValue: mediaPlayer.volume = 1.0

            property bool sync: false

            onValueChanged: {
                if (!sync)
                    mediaPlayer.seek(value)
            }

            Connections {
                target: mediaPlayer
                onPositionChanged: {
                    volumeSlider.sync = true
                    volumeSlider.value = mediaPlayer.volume
                    volumeSlider.sync = false
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
onClicked: 
  { mediaPlayer.muted = true; }
```

Set to false if you want to unmute.